# Chicken-and-egg problem for enrolling kids in school in Spain

Tags: student-visa, spain, children

My wife and I hope to take our two minor children for a school year in Asturias, Spain. The kids seemingly need to obtain student visas for minors, but two parts of the puzzle may be in conflict.

The [visa application](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/SANFRANCISCO/en/ConsularServices/Consular-Services-in-San-Francisco/Documents/Student%20Visa%20for%20Minors%20%28Under%2018%20Years%29%20Guidelines.pdf) calls for "An acceptance letter from public or private school in Spain you will be attending, confirming your status as a full time student in Spain." Meanwhile, we have not been able to take part in the normal school enrollment process, which depends on being resident in Spain. I contacted several primary schools and they pointed me towards a quick process of "extraordinary matriculation" which we can begin once we have an address in Spain. Of course, now applying for our visas and identification numbers, we have not yet been able to arrive and rent an apartment.

Which came first, the chicken or the egg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chicken comes first, since you are taking your children with you.

Apply for their visas, togeather with yours, for this purpose.
Once an D-Visa has been issued, the school enrollment process can start.

The **STUDENT VISA for Minors (Under 18 Years)** seems to be intended more for children that will **not** be accompanied by their parents (thus the need for **Parental authorization to travel** in the application).

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't noticed that some (not all) of the visas also apply to spouses and children as a unit.